# Deploying to Heroku: CodeRay is not Precompiled - How to remove?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, coderay

I'm learning Rails and read about using CodeRay to have lovely syntax highlighting in your page. When I use `rails server` it's fine and everything is hunky dory, but when I try to deploy to Heroku I get the useful "something went wrong" page. According to the logs, `ActionView::Template::Error (coderay.css isn't precompiled):`. So I want to remove CodeRay from my Rails app for now.

I removed the CSS file, the link in the erb file, CodeRay from my Gemfile, ran `bundle install` and `bundle update` for good measure, but I still get the same error.

```
2012-05-27T07:41:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 98ms
2012-05-27T07:41:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-05-27T07:41:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <html>
2012-05-27T07:41:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <head>
2012-05-27T07:41:22+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (coderay.css isn't precompiled):
2012-05-27T07:41:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", "coderay", :media => "all" %>
2012-05-27T07:41:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <title>RG Simms</title>
2012-05-27T07:41:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2012-05-27T07:41:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2012-05-27T07:41:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <link rel="/favicon.ico" alt="gentlemanraptor">
```

Now, this is really weird. I have removed the `stylesheet_link_tag` to coderay in the html.erb, uninstall the actual gem completely, and deployed to Heroku again, but with the same error.

Currently using the cedar stack and rails 3.2.3.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell rails to precompile coderay.css along with your other assets:

```
# application.rb
config.precompile += %w(coderay.css)
```

Try that.

If it still doesn't work you probably need to remove the stylesheet link tag to coderay, since it will get bundled with your application.rb during asset precompilation

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile your assets locally first.

Take a look here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar

Try the below before pushing to Heroku.

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: I did that to no avail. The problem now is that even if I alter my html.erb file the changes don't appear on Heroku. It still thinks that the link to CodeRay.css is there when it isn't.